# ejabberd and MS SQL on Windows?

Tags: windows, sql-server, xmpp, ejabberd

Is it correct that if I install ejabberd on Windows machine I cannot use MS SQL instead of Mnesia? https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#microsoft-sql-notes seems to suggest it, it says, "For now, MS SQL is only supported in Unix-like OS'es". This sounds strange, because

1. ejabberd works fine on Windows;
2. Windows is the native environment for SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in that same paragraph it says that ejabberd uses FreeTDS and unixODBC libraries. If any of those is not available in Windows, then... that specific feature does not work in Windows.

Comment: There is FreeTDS port to Windows, but not unixODBC for Windows.
It's a very strange, perhaps perverted situation, ejabberd works on Windows, MS SQL is native on Windows and was only ported to Linux, but ejabberd cannot work with MS SQL on Windows...